# printing the files serially using glob

Tags: python, sorting, glob

I have files in a directory. And the files are named as `1.txt,2.txt,...10.txt...150.txt.`

When I use glob function it randomly arranged the files as

```
1.txt,10.txt....so on
```

however i want the files to be arranged serially like `1.txt,2.txt...10.txt,11.txt...`

i tried the function

```
import glob
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt')):
    print(filename)
```

I hope experts may help me overcoming this problem.

Comment: You probably want a "natural sort", search for that.

Comment: natural sort didnot work can u please show it how to use @MarkRansom

Comment: I told you to search because I didn't feel like answering a question that has already been answered a thousand times. And you need to be more explicit about "did not work".

Comment: i tried like natural sort(glob.glob(...))) but it didnot work

Comment: It's obvious to me that you didn't search for the term "natural sort" and still don't know what it means. And you never explained what "didnot work" means exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `sorted` will sort the filenames as *strings*. That will produce unwanted results:

```
In [1]: names = [str(n)+".txt" for n in range(1,21)];

In [2]: ' '.join(sorted(names[4:14]))
Out[2]: '10.txt 11.txt 12.txt 13.txt 14.txt 5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt'
```

You want to sort the filenames numerically. In this case that can be done with a special `key` function that converts the filename to an integer.

In the case of the example above, like this:

```
In [3]: ' '.join(sorted(names[4:14], key=lambda s: int(s[:-4])))
Out[3]: '5.txt 6.txt 7.txt 8.txt 9.txt 10.txt 11.txt 12.txt 13.txt 14.txt'
```

Or in your code:

```
import glob
for filename in sorted(glob.glob('*.txt'), key=lambda s: int(s[:-4])):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you @Roland Smith